# Stop UITableView's tableHeaderView from autoscrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a pretty large view being used as my `tableHeaderView` (not a section header) for a `UITableView`. When scrolling, it seems that the table view must display either the entire `tableHeaderView` or none of it. If I scroll down just a bit, the table view scrolls back to the top of the header view when I release. If I scroll down just over halfway down the `tableHeaderView`, the table view scrolls down farther to hide the entire `tableHeaderView` when I release.

This is causing very jumpy scrolling for the user. Is there any way to disable this so that you can scroll down the `tableHeaderView` partially.

To clarify, this is not a question about making the `tableHeaderView` float. I want the header view to scroll with the table view, I just don't want this jumpy scrolling behavior.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to convert it to a cell. So you'd have section 0 with 1 cell - the header cell, and all your content would be moved one section down.

Comment: Yeah, that would be pretty complicated in this case. I'm using a view controller from a third-party library to display a picker for a contact from the user's address book. Adding a `tableHeaderView` is simple, but altering the datasource won't be.